# Rule for all functions in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want make "rule" for all functions in my controller. Example - in my AdminController i want this function(down) work for all functions without having to write it in every new function.

```
if(session('Admin')) {

        $accinfo = DB::Table('MEMB_INFO')->count();
        $charinfo = DB::Table('Character')->count();


        return view('ap.home', ['accinfo' => $accinfo, 'charinfo' => $charinfo]);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('adminpanel/login');
    }`
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? is this the `index` method? are you using Laravel Spatie Permission?

Comment: Do all of your controllers extend a certain controller? Place it there

Comment: @didenetahi I dont use Spatie Permission. I just want "main function" work for all function in controllers without need to call.

Comment: @brombeer More example - I want a function that can monitor all functions in the admin panel if the user has an available session

Comment: I would place the `redirect` logic into [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware) and then apply that middleware to the desired routes. The logic for obtaining `character` and `account` information could be added to the `__construct` function of your `AdminController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can use middleware and use it in the constructor method for the relevant controller.

You can also browse Traits if you want to include a specific code block in the controller by simply saying use it.

Or, you can create a helper file according to your needs and call the relevant functions from there.